# Tableau - Filter has one value always selected

Tags: tableau-api

I need to create a dashboard in which there is one chart with bars for different Product Types. I am using this chart as a filter. I want one value of Product Type as always selected while I can select/deselect other product types.

For Example I have 4 product Types - A,B,C,D. I want A to be always selected while I can select one of B, C or D to filter other charts based on this selection.

I can have the product type A hidden from the chart too.

Comment: Obviously this will depend on your data, but you could create an action filter which has category A selected - you can then hide this filter so it cannot be changed by the viewer of the published dashboard. A screenshot of your report would be helpful to help visualize what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

I hope if you follow the steps given in below answer then you should be able to solve your issue.
[Hide value in filter - Tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44827291/hide-value-in-filter-tableau/44911414#44911414)

The only change which you would require is in the definition of calculated field:

```
IF [parm_field] == 'All' THEN 'Y'
ELSE
  IF (([parm_field]=[dim_field]) or ([dim_field]=='0')) THEN 'Y'     //in your case just replace '0' by 'A'  
  ELSE 'N'
  END
END
```

*Kindly don't forget to let us know if it solves your problem :)*